# Type-conversion in update-statement fails

Tags: sql-server-2012, type-conversion

In the given scenario we have two tables:

1. ChangeLog: Containing historical values of a "field", stored as varchar(23).
2. ViewFields: Containing meta information about a "field", e.g. datatype, max value, min value, display name. This is for validation tasks and UI configuration.

The following statement shall update all historical values of all "fields" which are convertible to "DateTime":

```
BEGIN TRAN

UPDATE c
   SET c.OldValue = CONVERT(varchar(23), CONVERT(DATETIME, c.OldValue, 101), 21)
  FROM ChangeLog c
 WHERE c.FieldID IN (   SELECT v.FieldID
                          FROM ViewFields v
                         WHERE FieldDataType IN (4,5,6))
```

When executing the statement, I'm getting the following error message:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Assuming, that there are values in the result, which are not convertible, the following statement should fail as well:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(23), CONVERT(DATETIME, c.OldValue, 101), 21)
  FROM ChangeLog c
 WHERE c.FieldID IN (   SELECT v.FieldID
                          FROM ViewFields v
                         WHERE FieldDataType IN (4,5,6))
```

Surprisingly, the select statement does work without errors.
When I now try to execute the update statement again, it works as well.
To break the statement again, execute **DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS**.

In my opinion, the condition should always be evaluated first, before reading the value. But this seems to be obviously not the case in this example.
The problem seems to be related to the cache.
Execution plans are identical.

Can somebody explain what does happen here?

Possible solution would be to update the values using cursors, but in my opinion this is no clean solution.

Comment: It can not cast this `CONVERT(varchar(23), CONVERT(DATETIME, OldValue, 101), 21)` to datatype of column `OldValue`(possible datetime). The fact that you are selecting `SELECT OldValue = CONVERT....` is not what you think. Here OldValue is just an alias of expression and not a table column!

Comment: Sorry, was a copy and paste error in the question. Corrected this one.

Comment: I doesn't matter. What are you trying to do? What is the type of `OldValue`?

Comment: 'OldValue' is of type varchar(23) (see point 1 above). With the update statement, I am trying to convert the value in column 'OldValue', which is a date represented by a string, to another format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously the answer is in the fact how sql server engine processes the query. The conceptual query processing order is:

```
 1. from 
 2. where
 3. group by
 4. having
 5. select
 6. order by
```

But in reality engine can decide to change that ordering. It can evaluate `select` clause first and then apply filter from `where` clause. This depends on many factors. So actually this is what happents in your case.

Workaround is to first select data into temporary table and then apply casting to data in temp table.

Answer (score 0):

When you are converting a datetime to varchar, there is no need to specify the style parameter.

Consider this `CONVERT(varchar(23), CONVERT(DATETIME, c.OldValue, 101), 21)`

versus this `CONVERT(varchar(23), CONVERT(DATETIME, c.OldValue, 101))`